# Can someone share an example of using IBM MQ in go language?

Tags: go, ibm-mq

everybody. Has anyone ever used the experience of IBM provided by https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-golang to share?

here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "../ibmmq"
    "os"
    "strings"
    // "time"
)

func main() {
    var qMgrName string
    var qMgrObject ibmmq.MQObject
    var managedQObject ibmmq.MQObject
    var subObject ibmmq.MQObject
    var err error
    var qMgr ibmmq.MQQueueManager
    // var rc int
    var openOptions int32
    var qObject ibmmq.MQObject

if len(os.Args) != 5 {
    fmt.Println("clientconn <qmgrname> <channelname> <conname> <queuename>")
    fmt.Println("")
    fmt.Println("For example")
    fmt.Println("  clientconn QMGR1 \"SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN\" \"myhost.example.com(1414)\" \"LOCAL.QUEUE\"")
    fmt.Println("All parameters are required.")
    os.Exit(1)
}

connected := false

qMgrName = os.Args[1]

cno := ibmmq.NewMQCNO()
cd := ibmmq.NewMQCD()

cd.ChannelName = os.Args[2]
cd.ConnectionName = os.Args[3]

cno.ClientConn = cd
cno.Options = ibmmq.MQCNO_CLIENT_BINDING

userId := os.Getenv("MQSAMP_USER_ID")
if userId != "" {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    csp := ibmmq.NewMQCSP()
    csp.AuthenticationType = ibmmq.MQCSP_AUTH_USER_ID_AND_PWD
    csp.UserId = userId

    fmt.Println("Enter password : ")
    scanner.Scan()
    csp.Password = scanner.Text()

    cno.SecurityParms = csp
}

qMgr, err = ibmmq.Connx(qMgrName, cno)
// qMgr, err = ibmmq.Conn(qMgrName)
if err == nil {
    fmt.Printf("Connection to %s succeeded.\n", qMgrName)
    // d, _ := time.ParseDuration("5s")
    // time.Sleep(d)
    // qMgr.Disc()
} else {
    fmt.Printf("Connection to %s failed.\n", qMgrName)
    fmt.Println(err)
}

if err == nil {
    mqod := ibmmq.NewMQOD()

    openOptions = ibmmq.MQOO_OUTPUT + ibmmq.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING
    openOptions |= ibmmq.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF

    mqod.ObjectType = ibmmq.MQOT_Q
    mqod.ObjectName = os.Args[4]

    qObject, err = qMgr.Open(mqod, openOptions)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Opened queue", qObject.Name)
    }
}

if err == nil {
    putmqmd := ibmmq.NewMQMD()
    pmo := ibmmq.NewMQPMO()

    pmo.Options = ibmmq.MQPMO_SYNCPOINT | ibmmq.MQPMO_NEW_MSG_ID | ibmmq.MQPMO_NEW_CORREL_ID

    putmqmd.Format = "MQSTR"
    msgData := "Hello from Go"
    buffer := []byte(msgData)

    // mqod := ibmmq.NewMQOD()
    // openOptions = ibmmq.MQOO_INQUIRE + ibmmq.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING
    // mqod.ObjectType = ibmmq.MQOT_CHANNEL
    // mqod.ObjectName = qObject.Name
    err = qObject.Put(putmqmd, pmo, buffer)
    // err = qMgr.Put1(mqod, putmqmd, pmo, buffer)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Put message to", qObject.Name)
    }
}

if err == nil {
    err = qMgr.Cmit()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}

if err == nil {
    msgAvail := true

    for msgAvail == true {
        var datalen int

        getmqmd := ibmmq.NewMQMD()
        gmo := ibmmq.NewMQGMO()
        gmo.Options = ibmmq.MQGMO_NO_SYNCPOINT | ibmmq.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING
        gmo.Options |= ibmmq.MQGMO_WAIT
        gmo.WaitInterval = 3000
        buffer := make([]byte, 32768)

        datalen, err = qObject.Get(getmqmd, gmo, buffer)

        if err != nil {
            msgAvail = false
            fmt.Println(err)
            mqret := err.(*ibmmq.MQReturn)
            if mqret.MQRC == ibmmq.MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE {
                err = nil
            }
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("Got message of length %d: ", datalen)
            fmt.Println(strings.TrimSpace(string(buffer[:datalen])))
        }
    }
}

if err == nil {
    err = qObject.Close()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Closed queue")
    }
}

if err == nil {
    mqsd := ibmmq.NewMQSD()
    mqsd.Options = ibmmq.MQSO_CREATE
    mqsd.Options |= ibmmq.MQSO_NON_DURABLE
    mqsd.Options |= ibmmq.MQSO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING
    mqsd.Options |= ibmmq.MQSO_MANAGED
    mqsd.ObjectString = "$SYS/MQ/INFO/QMGR/" + qMgrName + "/ActivityTrace/ApplName/mqitest"

    subObject, err = qMgr.Sub(mqsd, &managedQObject)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Subscribed to topic ", mqsd.ObjectString)
    }
}

if err == nil {
    msgAvail := true

    for msgAvail == true {
        var datalen int

        getmqmd := ibmmq.NewMQMD()
        gmo := ibmmq.NewMQGMO()
        gmo.Options = ibmmq.MQGMO_NO_SYNCPOINT | ibmmq.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING
        gmo.Options |= ibmmq.MQGMO_WAIT
        gmo.WaitInterval = 3000
        buffer := make([]byte, 32768)

        datalen, err = managedQObject.Get(getmqmd, gmo, buffer)

        if err != nil {
            msgAvail = false
            fmt.Println(err)
            mqret := err.(*ibmmq.MQReturn)
            if mqret.MQRC == ibmmq.MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE {
                // not a real error so reset err, but
                // end retrieval loop
                err = nil
            }
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("Got message of length %d. Format = %s\n", datalen, getmqmd.Format)
        }
    }
}

if err == nil {
    subObject.Close()
}

if err == nil {
    mqod := ibmmq.NewMQOD()
    openOptions = ibmmq.MQOO_INQUIRE + ibmmq.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING

    mqod.ObjectType = ibmmq.MQOT_Q_MGR
    mqod.ObjectName = qMgrName

    qMgrObject, err = qMgr.Open(mqod, openOptions)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Opened QMgr for MQINQ\n")
    }
}

if err == nil {
    selectors := []int32{ibmmq.MQCA_Q_MGR_NAME,
        ibmmq.MQCA_DEAD_LETTER_Q_NAME,
        ibmmq.MQIA_MSG_MARK_BROWSE_INTERVAL}

    intAttrs, charAttrs, err := qMgrObject.Inq(selectors, 2, 160)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        returnedName := string(charAttrs[0:48])
        fmt.Printf("MQINQ returned +%v %s \n",
            intAttrs, string(charAttrs))
        fmt.Printf("               '%s'\n", returnedName)
    }

}

if connected {
    err = qMgr.Disc()
    fmt.Println("Disconnected from queue manager ", qMgrName)
}

if err == nil {
    os.Exit(0)
} else {
    mqret := err.(*ibmmq.MQReturn)
    os.Exit((int)(mqret.MQCC))
}

}
```

but is always show fatal error:

```
[root@localhost clientconn]# ./clientconn QM_T01 "JMS" "127.0.0.1(1414)" "LQ"
Connection to QM_T01 succeeded.
Opened queue LQ
fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x80 addr=0x0 pc=0x7f214ba2b414]

runtime stack: runtime.throw(0x4ebdce, 0x2a)
    /home/app/go/src/runtime/panic.go:605 +0x95 runtime.sigpanic()
    /home/app/go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:351 +0x2b8

goroutine 1 [syscall, locked to thread]: runtime.cgocall(0x49ed30,
0xc42004f9c8, 0x100)    /home/app/go/src/runtime/cgocall.go:132 +0xe4
fp=0xc42004f980 sp=0xc42004f940 pc=0x4072c4
_/svr/ibmmq/ibmmq._Cfunc_MQPUT(0x1000006, 0xc42007c000, 0xc4200720c0, 0xd, 0xc420016110, 0xc420016120, 0xc4200160fc)
    _/svr/ibmmq/ibmmq/_obj/_cgo_gotypes.go:887 +0x45 fp=0xc42004f9c8
sp=0xc42004f980 pc=0x4938e5
_/svr/ibmmq/ibmmq.MQObject.Put.func1(0x1000006, 0xc42007c000, 0xc4200720c0, 0xc40000000d, 0xc420016110, 0xc420016120, 0xc4200160fc)
    /svr/ibmmq/ibmmq/mqi.go:407 +0x10e fp=0xc42004fa10 sp=0xc42004f9c8
pc=0x49a69e
_/svr/ibmmq/ibmmq.MQObject.Put(0x0, 0xc42000c0a0, 0xc42001a0f0, 0x30, 0xc420078000, 0xc42007a000, 0xc420016110, 0xd, 0x10, 0x0, ...)
    /svr/ibmmq/ibmmq/mqi.go:407 +0x120 fp=0xc42004fa80 sp=0xc42004fa10
pc=0x495030 main.main()     /svr/ibmmq/clientconn/clientconn.go:102
+0x158e fp=0xc42004ff80 sp=0xc42004fa80 pc=0x49e29e runtime.main()  /home/app/go/src/runtime/proc.go:195 +0x226 fp=0xc42004ffe0
sp=0xc42004ff80 pc=0x42e9c6 runtime.goexit()
    /home/app/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2337 +0x1 fp=0xc42004ffe8
sp=0xc42004ffe0 pc=0x457491
```

Comment: What version of the IBM MQ client do you have installed?

Comment: @JoshMc 7.5.0.2

Comment: U SAVED ME , thanks for the snippet man it works as is

Answer (score 0):

The readme for mq-golang states you must be at a minimum of IBM MQ v9.

> A minimum level of MQ V9 is required to build this package. The monitoring data published by the queue manager is not available before that version; the interface also assumes availability of MQI structures from that level of MQ.

Comment: according to the error msg, it's when put message error, this is not use publish. code line 102 is err = qObject.Put(putmqmd, pmo, buffer) , /svr/ibmmq/clientconn/clientconn.go:102 +0x158e fp=0xc42004ff80 sp=0xc42004fa80 pc=0x49e29e

Comment: The readme states that it assumes availability of MQI structures from MQ v9. You are two levels of MQ behind what is the minimum requirement.  You should try to recreate this with the minimum.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tested it in version 9, and there's the same mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried using the latest MQ 9.1.1 CD version with go1.11.5 I had to make a slight modification to your code to add an int32 in the Close() calls to get it to compile, but it now compiles and runs fine on my Ubuntu 16.04 VM.

If rebuilding the MQ Go client with a later version of MQ you should use the -a flag on go install to force it to rebuild everything rather than cache the bit its already built, you could still be using code compiled against the old MQ libraries.